# Can't print the result on the eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, console, return, system.out

I'm trying to create a program to calculate the factorial of a number.
The console doesn't show any errors but also doesn't show any results.
What am I doing wrong?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
  
    public static int faculty(int n) {
       n=5;
        int x = 1;
        if(n > 0){
            for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
                x = x*i;
            }
    
        }
        System.out.println(x);
        return x;

    }
    
  
}
```

Comment: Please do not completely rewrite questions!

Answer (score 1):

You never invoke the faculty(...) method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    faculty( 5 );
}
```

You would also get rid of:

```
n=5;
```

That defeats the purpose of passing a parameter to the method if you always hard code a value.

Also, why would you call the method "faculty"? Maybe something more descriptive like `calculateFactorial` for the method name, since that is what is what you are trying to calculate. Make you method names descriptive so we have an ideas what the method does.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.